# How to stop Docker process from docker hub container busybox?

Tags: docker, terminal, process, daemon

I don't have any docker containers locally, running them from docker hub.

I ran `docker run busybox ping google.com`

Then I closed my terminal before stopping the process. Now it seems like I can't stop the process:

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
138faab6c40f        busybox             "ping google.com"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes       musing_hopper
➜  ~ docker stop busybox
Error response from daemon: No such container: busybox
➜  ~ docker stop busybox
Error response from daemon: No such container: busybox
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/#description

> $ docker stop my_container

Also tried

```
➜  ~ docker kill busybox
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: busybox: No such container: busybox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stop command accepts the container name or id which is different from the image name, which in this case is busybox.

To stop the container, you first need to figure out its name or id, which can be found by running `docker container ls` and then use the Id or name as input to the stop command:

```
docker stop <container-name-or-id>
```

Comment: Just tried, but I got `Error: No such container: busybox` I don't have any containers locally

Comment: @LeonGaban updated answer, after seeing the error message you were getting

Answer (score 1):

A good command to stop all your running docker containers, in case you closed the terminal before stopping them is:

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker stop
```